# How to Set All Objects to the Same Mode Via Scripting?

Tags: python, mesh, scripting

Is there a way through scripting to set all meshes in a scene to the same mode at the same time without selecting each one and doing it manually? IE set all to object mode, or set all to texture paint mode?

Comment: All objects are by definition in *Object Mode* always, only one object can be edited at any time, through scripting or otherwise, this is a fundamental part of Blender design.

Answer (score 1):

The mode can only be changed for the active object, all other objects *must* be in object mode.

There is an addon that does some tricks to allow [editing multiple objects](https://github.com/antoni4040/MultiEdit-Addon) at once.

Answer (score 1):

`for obj in bpy.context.scene.objects:
    if not obj.hide:
        bpy.context.scene.objects.active = obj
        bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')`

Referring to the previous answers - object may stay in Vertex Paint, sculpting and Weight Paint, Texture Paint modes while not being active. However, there can only be one object in Edit mode.